# DoubleTap in android

Tags: android

I need to create a small text area.Within that text area when i double click,it will move to next activity.How could i do this?

Comment: A longclick or a button would be a more common way to achieve this. A similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217670/question-how-to-implement-android-double-tap

Answer (score 62):

If you do the setup right, the `OnDoubleTapListener`, within the `GestureListener`is very useful. You dont need to handle each single tap and count time in between. Instead let Android handle for you what a tap, a double-tap, a scroll or fling might be. With the helper class `SimpleGestureListener` that implements the `GestureListener` and `OnDoubleTapListener` you dont need much to do.

```
findViewById(R.id.touchableText).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(Test.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("TEST", "onDoubleTap");
            return super.onDoubleTap(e);
        }
        ... // implement here other callback methods like onFling, onScroll as necessary
    });

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("TEST", "Raw event: " + event.getAction() + ", (" + event.getRawX() + ", " + event.getRawY() + ")");
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Note: I tested around quite a while to find out, what the right mixture of `return true` and `return false` is. This was the really tricky part here.

Another note: When you test this, do it **on a real device**, instead of the emulator. I had real trouble getting the mouse fast enough to create an onFling event. Real fingers on real devices seem to be much faster.

Comment: This was really perfect for my case. I needed to prevent user from triggering an animation multiple times. Thx a lot.

Comment: Worked great for me! One thing I did have to do is drop the "Test.this" parameter for the GestureDetector. It is depreciated but it works. I kept getting an error: "Error:(35, 79) error: not an enclosing class: Test". Any idea what might have caused that?

Comment: I found a fix to be able to pass the context. Add this to the onCreate():

final Context context = getApplicationContext();

Then pass "context" rather than "Test.this".

Comment: this works well. But it breaks scrolling in the textview.

Comment: Bonus points for an excellent use of anon-classes.

Answer (score 32):

A better alternative is to create a lightweight Abstract Class

```
public abstract class DoubleClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    private static final long DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA = 300;//milliseconds

    long lastClickTime = 0;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        long clickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (clickTime - lastClickTime < DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA){
            onDoubleClick(v);
            lastClickTime = 0;
        } else {
            onSingleClick(v);
        }
        lastClickTime = clickTime;
    }

    public abstract void onSingleClick(View v);
    public abstract void onDoubleClick(View v);
}
```

And use it like

```
 view.setOnClickListener(new DoubleClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSingleClick(View v) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDoubleClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: will it not call both onsingleclick and ondoubleclick when user tries to double click?

Comment: The system double tap timeout is `ViewConfiguration.getDoubleTapTimeout() `.

Comment: You will always get singleClick. There needs to be a timer of 300ms

Answer (score 17):

very simple logic use below code

```
    boolean firstTouch = false;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == event.ACTION_DOWN){
                if(firstTouch && (Helper.getCurrentTimeInMilliSeconds() - time) <= 300) {
                    //do stuff here for double tap
                    Log.e("** DOUBLE TAP**"," second tap ");
                    firstTouch = false;

                } else {
                    firstTouch = true;
                    time = Helper.getCurrentTimeInMilliSeconds();
                    Log.e("** SINGLE  TAP**"," First Tap time  "+time);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: `long time= System.currentTimeMillis();` and `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of `Helper.getCurrentTimeInMilliSeconds()`

Answer (score 5):

### ----------

I took a different approach for implementing double-tap on android views. I created my own logic for detecting double tap and it's very easy to implement.

> Here are the steps for doing this:
>   1. Set onTouchListener on the view you want to receive the touch event.
>   2. Implement the onTouch(view,event) method. (In double tap the key is to detect two ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP events. For this we will have to calculate the time duration between two successive down-up events).

Here is the logic for achieving this:

```
    /* variable for counting two successive up-down events */
int clickCount = 0;
/*variable for storing the time of first click*/
long startTime;
/* variable for calculating the total time*/
long duration;
/* constant for defining the time duration between the click that can be considered as double-tap */
static final MAX_DURATION = 500;
@Override
public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            clickCount++;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            duration=  duration + time;
            if(clickCount == 2)
            {
                if(totalTime <= DURATION)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(captureActivity.this, "double tap",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                clickCount = 0;
                duration = 0;
                break;             
            }
    }
    return true;    
}
```

==== EDIT ======

For me the above is not acceptable with the changes suggested in the cooment - the time out does not work for the above logic.

use this instead

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
    {

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        clickCount++;

        if (clickCount==1){
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        else if(clickCount == 2)
        {
            long duration =  System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            if(duration <= ONE_SECOND)
            {                    
                    Toast.makeText(captureActivity.this, "double tap",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                clickCount = 0;
                duration = 0;
            }else{
                clickCount = 1;
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            break;             
        }
}
return true;
```

}

Comment: A few small changes were necessary to make the above work.                                                                
1) change:     static final MAX_DURATION = 500;
to  static final int MAX_DURATION = 500;

2) change:       if(totalTime <= DURATION)    to    if(duration <= MAX_DURATION)

Comment: birdman your changes helped but the timeout does not work, check my edit for corrected timeout logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
X_View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view) 
            {
    long timeNow=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    long timeLastTapped=Long.valueOf(view.getTag().toString()); // Initially set to zero in adapter
    final int minDurationBetweenDoubleTap=500;
    if(timeLastTapped != 0)
            if( timeNow- timeLastTapped < minDurationBetweenDoubleTap) 
                        {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DoubleTapped", 10).show(); 
                        }
    view.setTag(""+timeNow); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class SimpleGestureFilter extends SimpleOnGestureListener
{
 public final static int SWIPE_UP    = 1; 
 public final static int SWIPE_DOWN  = 2; 
 public final static int SWIPE_LEFT  = 3; 
 public final static int SWIPE_RIGHT = 4;  
 public final static int MODE_TRANSPARENT = 0; 
 public final static int MODE_SOLID = 1; 
 public final static int MODE_DYNAMIC = 2;  
 private final static int ACTION_FAKE = -13;  
 private int swipe_Min_Distance = 100; 
 private int swipe_Max_Distance = 350; 
 private int swipe_Min_Velocity = 100;  
 private int mode = MODE_DYNAMIC; 
 private boolean running = true; 
 private boolean tapIndicator = false;  
 private Activity context; 
 private GestureDetector detector; 
 private SimpleGestureListener listener;   
 public SimpleGestureFilter(Activity context,SimpleGestureListener sgf) 
 {   
  this.context = context;  
  this.detector = new GestureDetector(context, this);  
  this.listener = sgf;  
 }
 public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) 
 {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if(!this.running)
   return;
  boolean result=this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
  if(this.mode==MODE_SOLID)
   me.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
  else if(this.mode==MODE_DYNAMIC)
  {
   if(me.getAction()==ACTION_FAKE)
    me.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
   else if(result)
    me.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
   else if(this.tapIndicator)
   {
    me.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
    this.tapIndicator=false;
   }
  } 
 }
 public void setMode(int m)
 {
  this.mode=m;
 }
 public int getMode()
 {
  return this.mode;
 }
 public void setEnabled(boolean status)
 {
  this.running=status;
 }
 public void setSwipeMaxDistance(int distance)
 {
  this.swipe_Max_Distance=distance;
 }
 public void setSwipeMinDistance(int distance)
 {
  this.swipe_Min_Distance=distance;
 }
 public int getSwipeMaxDistance()
 {  
  return this.swipe_Max_Distance; 
 }  
 public int getSwipeMinDistance()
 {  
  return this.swipe_Min_Distance; 
 }  
 public int getSwipeMinVelocity()
 {  
  return this.swipe_Min_Velocity; 
 }

 public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1,MotionEvent e2,float velocityX,float velocityY)
 {
  final float xDistance=Math.abs(e1.getX()-e2.getX());
  final float yDistance=Math.abs(e1.getY()-e2.getY());
  if(xDistance>this.swipe_Max_Distance || yDistance> this.swipe_Max_Distance)

   return false;
  velocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
  velocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
  boolean result=false;
  if(velocityX > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && xDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance)
  {
   if(e1.getX() > e2.getX()) // right to left Move
    this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_LEFT);
   else
    this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_RIGHT);
   result=true;
  }
  else if(velocityY > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && yDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance)
  {
   if(e1.getY() > e2.getY()) // bottom to top Move
    this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_UP);
   else
    this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_DOWN);
   result=true;
  }
  return result;
 }
 public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) 
 {
  this.tapIndicator=true;
  return false;
 }
 public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) 
 {
  this.listener.onDoubleTap();
  return false;
 } 
 public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) 
 {    
  return true;
 }
 public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) 
 {
  if(this.mode==MODE_DYNAMIC)
  {
   e.setAction(ACTION_FAKE);
   this.context.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
  }
  return false;
 }
 static interface SimpleGestureListener
 {     
  void onSwipe(int direction);     
  void onDoubleTap();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had i similar problem and the solutions work until i wanted to do other touch events like swiping and onLongPress. Those methods were never invoked so I had to implement an OnDoubleTapListener. I did as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnDoubleTapListener
```

Then just implement three methods

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    if(e.getAction()==1)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DOUBLE TAP",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Implement code here!!!
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    return true;
}
```

Just implement the onDoubleTapEvent method.
I don't know when the other two methods are invoked, but this works for me

Comment: how to set the listener?