# How to implement doubletap on imageview's onclick?

Tags: android

I have an imageview. I need to start animation with different speed on double tap and singletap. On doubletap speed is fast and on singletap speed is back to normal speed.

How can I implement gestures on imageview's onclick?

Answer (score 12):

if you do not wish to go for custom image view then you can use following approach

```
// class level

GestureDetector gestureDetector;
boolean tapped;
ImageView imageView;

// inside onCreate of Activity or Fragment
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),new GestureListener());
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
public class GestureListener extends
            GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {

            return true;
        }

        // event when double tap occurs
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

            tapped = !tapped;

            if (tapped) {



            } else {



            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

for ImageView

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Oh i was missing returning true in `onDown(MotionEvent e)`

Comment: No need tapped  variables and it's if else situations. You detect already double tap in onDoubleTap method.

Comment: hello how to get the application context in the gisturelistener ?

Comment: @Z.Kiwan Either you can pass it to this class or you can create singleton inside your application class and use it.  E.g. MyApplication.getInstance()

Answer (score 5):

You can implement a gesture listener for catching the double tap for example like that:

```
public class MyView extends ImageView {

    GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // creating new gesture detector
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    }

    // skipping measure calculation and drawing

    // delegate the event to the gesture detector
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
    }


    private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
        // event when double tap occurs
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            float x = e.getX();
            float y = e.getY();

            Log.d("Double Tap", "Tapped at: (" + x + "," + y + ")");

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to use gesturelistener, create your own custom imageview then override the ontouchEvent like this:

```
long t1 = 0, t2 = 0;
int count = 0;
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

    int action = e.getAction();
    switch (action){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(count == 0) {
                t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            if(count == 1){
                t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            count++;
            if(count > 1) count = 0;
            Log.d("DoubleTapImageView", "down t1: " + String.valueOf(t1) + " t2: " + String.valueOf(t2) + "," + String.valueOf(t2-t1));
            if(Math.abs(t2 - t1) < 300){
                t1 = t2 = 0; count = 0;
                // On double tap here. Do stuff
            }

            break;

    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(e);
}
```

By this way, you can control the duration time

Comment: The system double tap timeout is `ViewConfiguration.getDoubleTapTimeout() `.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener on your activity. Then you will get onDoubleTap event. For more details you can refer same posts over here:

[DoubleTap in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804798/doubletap-in-android)

[Android: How to detect double-tap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217670/question-how-to-implement-android-double-tap)