# How do I make imageView respond to double tap and recognize when imageView is pressed, unpressed(action down, up)?

Tags: android, gesture, tap, motionevent, gesturedetector

I want image to respond to 3 actions:

image pressed(action down)  - image becomes large
 image unpressed(action up) - image becomes normal size again
 double tap on image - image moves somewhere

I have been trying to do it this way:

```
public class Working_gestures extends Activity {
ImageView sample ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sample = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sample);

    Gestures x = new Gestures(sample);

}
 //inner class
private class Gestures extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener implements View.OnTouchListener{

    ImageView view ;
    public Gestures(ImageView v) {
        view = v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        //must return true for doubleTap to work, but onDown() "blocks" onTouch
        return true ;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e){
         //do something on image
         return true ;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //image increases in size and stays large
                Log.wtf("x", "action down");
                break ;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //image comes back to normal size
                Log.wtf("x", "action up!");
                break ;
        }
        return true ;
    }
}
```

}

But onTouch is never triggered! Because onDown (aka MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) fires up onDoubleTap and others - singletap, fling etc.

I also tried to override onShowPress() - but it only recognizes action down. single tap up, singleTapconfirmed() did not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after struggling so much with gesture listener and its methods - onFling, onLongPress etc I decided to write my own, my idea is not that different from recording the time of of each press, there is similar solution on SO.

I understand what my problem was: **if you use onTouch** - all your touches are intercepted and interpreted through it, but simpleGestureListener processes its own events through onDown, so onTouch is never called; in this situation I had to write pretty basic logic:

- on ACTION_DOWN, launch count down timer for 300 miliseconds or so - after it **ticks** around 290, check again if the event is still action down
- if event is action down - it is essentially long press and my image responds accordingly - becomes larger, if not - just do nothing
- on ACTION_UP: check if it was long press, if it was - the user unpressed his hold, and image becomes smaller, but otherwise - **it was quick tap!**

Code below:

```
public class DoubleTapWorking1 extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {
ImageView sample;
boolean still_down ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sample = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sample);
    sample.setOnTouchListener(this);
    still_down = false ;

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View v,final MotionEvent e) {

     switch (e.getAction()){
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             still_down =false;
             CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(500,10){
                 @Override
                 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                     if((int)millisUntilFinished < 100 && e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                         still_down = true ;
                     }
                 }
                 @Override
                 public void onFinish() {
                     if( still_down){                           
                         //code to make imageView larger
                     }
                 }
             }.start();
             break ;
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             if(still_down) {
                 //your code to make image smaller
             }
             else{
                 action_on_single_tap(v);
             }
             break ;
     }

   return true;
  }

  private void action_on_single_tap(final View v){
      //your code to do with image on single tap - move somewhere else, make invisible etc.
}
```

}

**EDIT: another better solution.**

I had some problems with countdown timer - it did not count down to the end for some reason. I applied some old idea - distinguish between long click and click using 2 listeners - LongClickListener, ClickListener. This worked out much better than the solution above.

Code below:

```
private class Gestures_future implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{

     int margin_long_press_x1;
     int margin_long_press_y1;
     int margin_long_press_x2;
     int margin_long_press_y2;
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_generic = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
public Gestures_future(final int margin_long_press_x1,final int margin_long_press_y1,final int margin_long_press_x2,final int margin_long_press_y2
    ){
        params_generic.leftMargin = 30;
        params_generic.topMargin = 40;

        this.margin_long_press_x1 = margin_long_press_x1;
        this.margin_long_press_y1 = margin_long_press_y1;
        this.margin_long_press_x2 = margin_long_press_x2;
        this.margin_long_press_y2 = margin_long_press_y2;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.wtf("x", "on click!");
        TextView d = (TextView)v;
        int current_id = v.getId();
       String answer_content = d.getText().toString();
        if (answers_player1_ids.contains(current_id)) {
        if (Battlefield.getStateOfAnswer1PlacePlayer1() == false) {
            d.setText("");
            Battlefield.answer1_place_busy_player1 = true;
            answer_place1_player1.setTextSize(20);
            answer_place1_player1.setText(answer_content);
            upper_layout_answer_counter++;
        } else if (Battlefield.getStateOfAnswer2PlacePlayer1() == false) {
            d.setText("");
            Battlefield.answer2_place_busy_player1 = true;
            answer_place2_player1.setTextSize(20);
            answer_place2_player1.setText(answer_content);
            upper_layout_answer_counter++;
            if (upper_layout_answer_counter == 2) {
                upper_layout_answer_counter = 0;
                see_answers1.performClick();
            }
        }
    }
        else if (answers_player2_ids.contains(current_id)) {
        if (Battlefield.getStateOfAnswer1Place() == false){
            d.setText("");
            Battlefield.answer1_place_busy = true;
            answer_place1.setTextSize(20);
            answer_place1.setText(answer_content);
            lower_layout_answer_counter++;
        } else if (Battlefield.getStateOfAnswer2Place() == false) {
            d.setText("");
            Battlefield.answer2_place_busy = true;
            answer_place2.setTextSize(20);
            answer_place2.setText(answer_content);
            lower_layout_answer_counter++;
            if (lower_layout_answer_counter == 2) {
                lower_layout_answer_counter = 0;
                see_answers2.performClick();
            }
        }
    }
}
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v){
        Log.wtf("x", "on long click!");
        final TextView d = (TextView)v;
        Log.wtf("x", d.getText().toString() +  " long clicked!" );
                    d.setTextSize(30);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams x = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(350, 500);
                    x.setMargins(margin_long_press_x1, margin_long_press_y1, 0, 0);
                    d.setLayoutParams(x);
                    d.requestLayout();
        new CountDownTimer(3000,500){
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams t1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(130, 170);
                t1.setMargins(margin_long_press_x2, margin_long_press_y2, 0, 0);
                d.setTextSize(10);
                d.setLayoutParams(t1);
                d.requestLayout();
            }
        }.start();
        return true;
    }

}
```

The solution above works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are returning `true` from `onTouch`, which will eat up the event and no further listeners will be called.

If you use `OnLongClickListener` for image press instead of `ACTION_DOWN` event you will be able to intercept other events.

Additionally, you will have to return `true` only inside the `ACTION_UP` event of onTouch and false otherwise. also do not return true from `onDown` so events will not be eaten up.

change your `onTouch` like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //image comes back to normal size
                Log.wtf("x", "action up!");
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and use `OnLongClickListener` for press event.

Comment: then what should I do? i m actually changing my code now - i think i m getting it

Comment: i can not even get to onTouch method - the first thing that is executed is onDown()! all other gestures start with onDown - if ondown is false, no gestures will be recognized, listened to

Comment: then you should not return true from `onDown`. why you need to do that? also check updated answer.

Comment: i need to return true from onDown, because i also want to RECOGNIZE singletap or double tap

Comment: you need not to do that for single tap and double tap. use `onSingleTapConfirmed` for single tap. use `onDoubleTap` for double tap.

Comment: i have been struggling with writing class, could you assist me writing some pseudocode?

Comment: have you tried my suggestions? if yes post your latest code and problems.

Comment: yes, i m doing it now, let me show you my code in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91711/discussion-between-erjan-and-rahul-tiwari).

Comment: you confused the hell out of me, i dont' understand anything now

Comment: how do I attach those 3 methods - onDoubleTap, onsingleTapconfirmed , on doubletapEvent? they need a separate GestureDetector object,

Comment: you have done everything correct apart from returning  `true` and `false` at places. i made comments on how to correct them.

Comment: but i dont' know how to call those onDoubleTap , onSingleTap methods - where do I call them from?

Comment: oh you forgot to add gesturelistener to your image.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715915/how-to-implement-doubletap-on-imageviews-onclick