# android - how to make a layout not obscure a gesture?

Tags: android

Imagine you have a big linearlayout, let's call it **originalLayout** that has a gestureDetector set to it.
Then you also inflate a ReLayNewsItem layout and put it into the originalLayout.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RelativeLayout ReLayNewsItem = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsitem, null); 
...
originalLayout.addView(ReLayNewsItem);
```

Now gestureDetector works only on the empty space of the originalLayout and does not work where I have the ReLayNewsItem.

**What's the best way to make ReLayNewsItem not obscure gesture?**

*P.S. I can not set the same gestureDetector onto ReLayNewsItem.*

ReLayNewsItem.setClickable(false); - doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever there is touch/gesture/motion event on the `ReLayNewsItem`, let your layout consume it like returning `mGesture.onTouchEvent(ReLayNewsItem_event)` in your touch event method of ReLayNewsItem or `layout.dispatchTouchEvent(ReLayNewsItem_event)`.

Read `Event Handler` point here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Comment: hmm, didn't really get it, how do I pass it then to originalLayout?

Comment: I guess you have gesture listener for your original layout. When you have touch events on the ReLayNewsItem you just use your gesture listener instance to consume the event. See here how they are passing events to the gesture listener http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804798/doubletap-in-android

Comment: tried, but it gives me this error :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486178/anroid-dispatchtouchevent-gives-me-a-stackoverflowerror