# Android - dispatchTouchEvent gives me a StackOverflowError

Tags: android

Here I have a ViewFlipper with a setOnTouchListener that works fine. Then I inflate ReLayNewsItem and later I add it to ViewFlipper.

Now I want WebView (web) to listen for touch events and pass them on to the ViewFlipper.

```
    final ViewFlipper VFnewsFeed = new ViewFlipper(this);

    VFnewsFeed.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (gestureDetectorLR.onTouchEvent(event)) { return true; }
            else { return true; }
        }});

    ///////////////////

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout ReLayNewsItem = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsitem, null); 

    final WebView web = (WebView)ReLayNewsItem.findViewById(R.id.NewsItemWv);

    web.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            VFnewsFeed.dispatchTouchEvent(event); /// ERROR HERE!
            return false;
        }});
```

Yet it gives me this -

```
07-14 21:12:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14048): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 21:12:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14048): java.lang.StackOverflowError
07-14 21:12:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at life.iface.main$11.onTouch(main.java:1289)
07-14 21:12:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:4605)
07-14 21:12:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1518)
07-14 21:12:43.600: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1320)
...
```

Any ideas? Thanks! ;)

Comment: "StackOverflow" errors are the best ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you return `false` it means that the event is **unhandled**.

Depending on your needs try to return `true` or `VFnewsFeed.dispatchTouchEvent(event)` in `onTouch` method instead of `false`.

[Reference to documentatnion](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29)

Comment: tried both true and VFnewsFeed.dispatchTouchEvent(event), same error. :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374592/passing-touch-events-to-the-parent-view

Comment: didn't really get it. you think it should be done with onInterceptTouchEvent ?