# Implementing GestureDetector to Drag, DoubleTap and singleTap a ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I am trying to implement a ImageView which will have different reaction with each action(Drag, DoubleTap and Single Tap). What I am doing is based in this tutorial: 
[DoubleTap in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804798/doubletap-in-android)

Which I used to create my class:

```
public class MyIcon extends ImageView {

    GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // creating new gesture detector
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    }

    // skipping measure calculation and drawing

    // delegate the event to the gesture detector
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
    }


    private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
        // event when double tap occurs
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            //A Toast just to see if it is working
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
            //A Toast just to see if it is working
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

To instantiate:

```
private WindowManager windowManager;
private MyIcon myIcon;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams params;

windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    chatHead = new MyIcon(this);
    chatHead.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT
    );

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;
```

I used a setOnTouchListener() which worked fine to make do Drag, but it is not work to DoubleTap.

Which would be the correct way to implement and instantiate this class to both work?

Answer (score 0):

**try this may help you SimpleGestureFilter**

```
public class SimpleGestureFilter extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    public final static int SWIPE_UP = 1;
    public final static int SWIPE_DOWN = 2;
    public final static int SWIPE_LEFT = 3;
    public final static int SWIPE_RIGHT = 4;

    public final static int MODE_TRANSPARENT = 0;
    public final static int MODE_SOLID = 1;
    public final static int MODE_DYNAMIC = 2;

    private final static int ACTION_FAKE = -13; // just an unlikely number
    private int swipe_Min_Distance = 100;
    private int swipe_Max_Distance = 350;
    private int swipe_Min_Velocity = 100;

    private int mode = MODE_DYNAMIC;
    private boolean running = true;
    private boolean tapIndicator = false;

    private Activity context;
    private GestureDetector detector;
    private SimpleGestureListener listener;

    public SimpleGestureFilter(Activity context, SimpleGestureListener sgl) {

        this.context = context;
        this.detector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
        this.listener = sgl;
    }

    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (!this.running)
            return;

        boolean result = this.detector.onTouchEvent(event);

        if (this.mode == MODE_SOLID)
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
        else if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) {

            if (event.getAction() == ACTION_FAKE)
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
            else if (result)
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
            else if (this.tapIndicator) {
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
                this.tapIndicator = false;
            }

        }
        // else just do nothing, it's Transparent
    }

    public void setMode(int m) {
        this.mode = m;
    }

    public int getMode() {
        return this.mode;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean status) {
        this.running = status;
    }

    public void setSwipeMaxDistance(int distance) {
        this.swipe_Max_Distance = distance;
    }

    public void setSwipeMinDistance(int distance) {
        this.swipe_Min_Distance = distance;
    }

    public void setSwipeMinVelocity(int distance) {
        this.swipe_Min_Velocity = distance;
    }

    public int getSwipeMaxDistance() {
        return this.swipe_Max_Distance;
    }

    public int getSwipeMinDistance() {
        return this.swipe_Min_Distance;
    }

    public int getSwipeMinVelocity() {
        return this.swipe_Min_Velocity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {

        final float xDistance = Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX());
        final float yDistance = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());

        if (xDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance
                || yDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance)
            return false;

        velocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
        velocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
        boolean result = false;

        if (velocityX > this.swipe_Min_Velocity
                && xDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance) {
            if (e1.getX() > e2.getX()) // right to left
                this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_LEFT);
            else
                this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_RIGHT);

            result = true;
        } else if (velocityY > this.swipe_Min_Velocity
                && yDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance) {
            if (e1.getY() > e2.getY()) // bottom to up
                this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_UP);
            else
                this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_DOWN);

            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        this.tapIndicator = true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg) {
        this.listener.onDoubleTap();
        ;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent arg) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg) {

        if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) { // we owe an ACTION_UP, so we fake an
            arg.setAction(ACTION_FAKE); // action which will be converted to an
                                        // ACTION_UP later.
            this.context.dispatchTouchEvent(arg);
        }

        return false;
    }

    static interface SimpleGestureListener {
        void onSwipe(int direction);

        void onDoubleTap();
    }

}
```

**Use in code this way**

```
   private SimpleGestureFilter detector;

   detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this, this);
```

**Just change in this method**

```
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        // Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
        this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
    }
```