# how to do something when the double touch on screen in android?

Tags: events, touch, double, tap, motion

how to do something when the   double     touch on screen in android?
 i have Use    SensorEventListener   ,
    SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_*

or use MostionEvent?

Comment: Do you mean a double tap? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804798/doubletap-in-android

Comment: i want to do something like turn on the screen or somethings... when i double touch!

Comment: Since the touch screen is off, it isn't listening for events, so that won't work. If the touchscreen (not even display) were always on and listening, it would obliterate any chance of good battery life. Also, I assure you that you don't actually want to do what you just said, even if you could. A double tap would invariably trigger while the phone is your pocket, and have the same result -- killing the battery.