# What is the difference between onDoubleTap listener and onDoubleTapEvent listener

Tags: java, android, event-listener

I am pretty new in Android, and recently learned about gestures!

What is the difference between 2 of these methods?

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}
```

And this one

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}
```

They seem to do the same thing. Which one do you use, and what is the difference

Comment: i edited the answer for a clear idea :) hope it will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simple answer will be

```
 boolean onDoubleTap (MotionEvent e) -
```

Notified when a **double-tap** occurs.

you can Notifi when a double-tap happens 
    and param `motionEvent` is forThe **down motion** event of the first tap.

```
  boolean onDoubleTapEvent (MotionEvent e)` -
```

Notified when an event within a **double-tap gesture** occurs

you can Notifi an event within a double-tap gesture occurs, including the `down`, `move`, and `up` events and and param `motionEvent` is for the The **motion event**

so with `doubleTapEvent` you can get additional tab gestures along with the tap

have a look --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/19629851/5188159 this might helpful for your touch gestures

further more try to understand what happens here with this example

```
//initialize the Gesture Detector  
        gd = new GestureDetector(this);  

        //set the on Double tap listener  
        gd.setOnDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTapListener()  
        {  
            @Override  
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)  
            {  
                //set text color to green  
                tvTap.setTextColor(0xff00ff00);  
                //print a confirmation message  
                tvTap.setText("The screen has been double tapped.");  
                return false;  
            }  

            @Override  
            public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e)  
            {  
                //if the second tap hadn't been released and it's being moved  
                if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)  
                {  
                    //set text to blue  
                    tvTapEvent.setTextColor(0xff0000ff);  
                    //print a confirmation message and the position  
                    tvTapEvent.setText("Double tap with movement. Position:\n"  
                            + "X:" + Float.toString(e.getRawX()) +  
                            "\nY: " + Float.toString(e.getRawY()));  
                }  
                else if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)//user released the screen  
                {  
                    tvTapEvent.setText("");  
                }  
                return false;  
            }  

            @Override  
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e)  
            {  
                //set text color to red  
                tvTap.setTextColor(0xffff0000);  
                //print a confirmation message and the tap position  
                tvTap.setText("Double tap failed. Please try again.");  
                return false;  
            }  
        });
```