# Click, Doble click and Hold Button

Tags: android, button, click

i have a little question. How can i implement click, doble click and hold in a Button. I really need add this functions to my button. I have AndroidStudio 2,3,3. Thanks you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`button.setOnLongClickListener` and `button.setOnClickListener` should do the trick for long and single clicks respectively.

For double tap here's what I do in the setOnClickListener.

```
boolean click=false;

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if(click==true)
    //DO SOMETHING 
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
              click=true;
        }, 1000};
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your activity has to implement the following interfaces: [`View.OnClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html), [`View.OnLongClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html).

When you have your ButtonId defined like this: `android:id="@+id/button"`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button: //what should happen when the button is pressed
            break;
    }
}
```

You also have to set the Listeners in `onCreate`:

```
setOnClickListener(this);
setOnLongClickListener(this);
```

The code for `onLongClick` looks exactly the same.

Double Tap is a bit more complicated, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19629851/7763268) you can find how to implement double tap.