# How to perform doubleClick event on an array of button

Tags: android, double-click

I have created an array of buttons. Now what I want is on double click of each of the buttons I want to display a toast which shows the text of the button which is clicked. I did it for singleClick but I don't know how to do it for doubleClick.

**The code I have written for an Array of buttons:**

```
LinearLayout layoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liVLayout);
    LinearLayout rowLayout = null;
    
    LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1);

    //Create Button
    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    {
        rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        rowLayout.setWeightSum(7);
        layoutVertical.addView(rowLayout, param);   
        
        for(int j=0; j<7; j++)
        {
            m_pBtnDay[i][j] = new Button(this);             
            m_pBtnDay[i][j].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            rowLayout.addView(m_pBtnDay[i][j], param);
            
            m_pBtnDay[i][j].setTextSize(12);
            //save button position
            m_pBtnDay[i][j].setTag(new CalendarForm(i , j));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you use DoubleTap of Gesture api. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849115/implement-double-click-for-button-in-android

Comment: how can i implement this code in my code..i look at that but dont know how to do it in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I can think of is by using Gesture Detection

```
 yourButton.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
```

.

```
 // Gesture detection
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());
    View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

// The onTouch method has a View parameter which is a reference to the touched view. Cast 
// this to Button to get its caption:

           String caption=((Button)v).getText();
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

.

```
private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
    // event when double tap occurs
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        Log.d("Double Click", "Tapped at: (" + x + "," + y + ")");

        return true;
    }
 }
```

Comment: how can i get the text of an button, to determine that this button is clicked

Comment: hey Reno what is gestureListener here

Comment: it is of the type `View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;`

Comment: how can i declared it...becoz on using this it show an error that undefined variable