# Single click and double click of a button in android

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

In my application i have a button. After single and double clicking of the button will perform separate operation. How can i do that? Thanks

Comment: simply set one globle variable count and increment in click event .when count=2 then perform double click operation and reset to count=0 .

Answer (score 11):

Well it is simple just override.

> onClick method of OnClickListener

```
public abstract class DoubleClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
private static final long DEFAULT_QUALIFICATION_SPAN = 200;
private boolean isSingleEvent;
private long doubleClickQualificationSpanInMillis;
private long timestampLastClick;
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;

public DoubleClickListener() {
    doubleClickQualificationSpanInMillis = DEFAULT_QUALIFICATION_SPAN;
    timestampLastClick = 0;
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (isSingleEvent) {
                onSingleClick();
            }
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - timestampLastClick) < doubleClickQualificationSpanInMillis) {
        isSingleEvent = false;
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        onDoubleClick();
        return;
    }

    isSingleEvent = true;
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, DEFAULT_QUALIFICATION_SPAN);
    timestampLastClick = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
}

public abstract void onDoubleClick();
public abstract void onSingleClick();
}
```

**Usage**

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new DoubleClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDoubleClick() {
            Log.i("onClick", "double");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSingleClick() {
            Log.i("onClick", "single");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer as it works exactly as expected

Comment: Best answer I could find too.  I posted a Kotlin translation in case anyone should find that useful.  Steve S.

Answer (score 9):

You may need to create a delay variable which will differenciate between single click and double click.

See this code,

```
private static final long DOUBLE_PRESS_INTERVAL = 250; // in millis
private long lastPressTime;

private boolean mHasDoubleClicked = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {    

        // Get current time in nano seconds.
        long pressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


        // If double click...
        if (pressTime - lastPressTime <= DOUBLE_PRESS_INTERVAL) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Double Click Event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mHasDoubleClicked = true;
        }
        else {     // If not double click....
            mHasDoubleClicked = false;
            Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
                 public void handleMessage(Message m) {
                      if (!mHasDoubleClicked) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Single Click Event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                 }
            };
            Message m = new Message();
            myHandler.sendMessageDelayed(m,DOUBLE_PRESS_INTERVAL);
        }
        // record the last time the menu button was pressed.
        lastPressTime = pressTime;      
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply. actually i need to know how can i apply it in a button as i m new in android

Comment: @ Rynold, I used your code, when I double click, code inside the single click also executes. Could you help me.

Comment: Why you use handler class @Raynold

Comment: I think you should use ViewConfiguration.getDoubleTapTimeout() for DOUBLE_PRESS_INTERVAL, to be consistent with other Android double taps.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to consider not using a DoubleTap.  It is not a normal Android behavior.

When I first started programming on the Android, I kept running into things that were really "hard" to do on the android.  Over time, I've found that many of them were difficult because they were a pretty bad idea.

If you are porting an iOS app, or emulating an iOS app's behavior, you may want to consider converting the UI over to Android style behaviors and use a longPress or other 'androidy' gestures.

Here is a similar question and answer:

[Android: How to detect double-tap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217670/android-how-to-detect-double-tap)

Answer (score 4):

You have to implement **GestureDetector** and put your code in `single/double click`.

**TestActivity.java**

```
iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //putyour first activity call.
                }
    }

iv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
             GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new MyGestureDetector(context));
         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
         }
});
```

Now you have to create `GestureDetector.java` class.

```
public class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    public Context context;
    public String phno;

    public MyGestureDetector(Context con) {
        this.context=con;       
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return super.onDown(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("in Double tap");

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("in single tap up");
            //put your second activity.
        return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    }   
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply.by this code when i try to perform operation for double touch it also perform single touch operation. how can i stop single touch operation when double touch?

Comment: @andDev you have to require same function call in single/double click so what problem?

Comment: actually i need to work with two activity for single and double touch

Comment: public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
//      System.out.println("in Double tap");
   flag = 2;
   Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Click2.class);
   startActivity(intent);
      return true;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
//      System.out.println("in single tap up");
   flag=1;   
   Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Click1.class);
   startActivity(intent);
      return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
  }

Comment: same problem. two activity starts in same time

Answer (score 3):

*Thanks* to *@NikolaDespotoski*.

You can check **DOUBLE-TAP** *example* from following **URL**.
that is used in listView. i hope it is useful for you.

https://nodeload.github.com/NikolaDespotoski/DoubleTapListView/zip/master

Answer (score 3):

Though it's too late, but anyone can figure out if they see this.

```
int number_of_clicks = 0;
boolean thread_started = false;
final int DELAY_BETWEEN_CLICKS_IN_MILLISECONDS = 250;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ++number_of_clicks;
        if(!thread_started){
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    thread_started = true;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(DELAY_BETWEEN_CLICKS_IN_MILLISECONDS);
                        if(number_of_clicks == 1){
                            client.send(AppHelper.FORMAT_LEFT_CLICK);
                        } else if(number_of_clicks == 2){
                            client.send(AppHelper.FORMAT_DOUBLE_CLICK);
                        }
                        number_of_clicks = 0;
                        thread_started = false;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
});
```

**Explanation:**

---

Before the button click, number_of_click is initialized to 0.
thread_started is a flag detecting if the thread is started before or not.
Now, on button click, increase the number of button click by incremental operator.
check if the thread is previously started or not, if not, then start the thread.
on thread, apply your logic by using the number_of_clicks. and the thread will wait for next milliseconds and then will go through your logic.
So, now you can apply as many clicks as you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is @saksham's answer in Kotlin.

```
abstract class DoubleClickListener : View.OnClickListener {
    private val DEFAULT_QUALIFICATION_SPAN = 200L
    private var isSingleEvent = false
    private val doubleClickQualificationSpanInMillis =
        DEFAULT_QUALIFICATION_SPAN
    private var timestampLastClick = 0L
    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private val runnable: () -> Unit = {
        if (isSingleEvent) {
            onSingleClick()
        }
    }
    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - timestampLastClick < doubleClickQualificationSpanInMillis) {
            isSingleEvent = false
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
            onDoubleClick()
            return
        }
        isSingleEvent = true
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, DEFAULT_QUALIFICATION_SPAN)
        timestampLastClick = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
    }

    abstract fun onDoubleClick()
    abstract fun onSingleClick()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solving this by inherit from the View.OnClickListener and checking the click time to distinguish the single click or double click, this also solve the problem of fast clicking. This solution will bring minor code change, just replace View.OnClickLister. You also can override the getGap() to redefine the time between two clicks.

```
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;

/*****
 * Implement to fix the double click problem.
 * Avoid the fast double click for button and images.
 */
public abstract class OnSingleClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private long prevClickTime =0;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        _onClick(v);
    }

    private synchronized void _onClick(View v){
        long current = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        if(current-prevClickTime> getGap()){
            onSingleClick(v);
            prevClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        }else {
            onDoubleClick(v);
            prevClickTime = 0;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onSingleClick(View v);
    public abstract void onDoubleClick(View v);

    /********
     *
     * @return The time in ms between two clicks.
     */
    public long getGap(){
        return 500L; //500ms
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**double click and single click in android**

**A solution that fits almost all versions**

**Detect** the type of **event** **within** the standard **duration** you want **to define** It can detect the event in an accelerated and
**sequential manner**, such as **passing** **a video** for a certain period

```
//general definition
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private int click_duble = 1;

button.setOnClickListener(view -> {

    if (countDownTimer == null) {
        float Second= (float) 0.25; //Detecting the type of event within a quarter of a second
        countDownTimer= new CountDownTimer((long) (Second * 1000), 50) {
            @Override public void onTick(long l){}
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if (click_duble >= 2) {
                    Toast.makeText(player_fb.this, "Double", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(player_fb.this, "Single", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                click_duble = 1;
                countDownTimer = null;
            }};countDownTimer.start();
    }else
        click_duble += 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The up solution cannot work for multi click, i test it but failed.

So i suggest to use RxBinding with ProgressDialog.

when click button, the progressDialog show setting it cannot be cancel, Fix it.

Answer (score 0):

on kotlin. add a class

```
class OnSingleClickListener(private val delay: Long) : View.OnClickListener {

private var lastClickTime = 0L

override fun onClick(view: View) {
    val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    if (currentTime - lastClickTime < delay) {
        return
    }
    lastClickTime = currentTime
}}
```

and use extension with adjustable delay

```
fun View.setOnSingleClickListener(delay: Long = 500L, block: () -> Unit{
setOnClickListener(OnSingleClickListener(delay, block))}
```

from [here](https://medium.com/@and_rey/singleclicklistener-debouncedclicklistener-for-android-app-1c55273fb1cf)

Answer (score -2):

I also got the same problem once

```
setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isFmOn()){
                   //stopFM
                }else{
                  //do other things
                }
            }
}
```

when I clicked the Button,FM stopped;but when I double clicked,FM did not stop.The problem was that single and double clicking of the button ,the value of isFmOn() was difference.
I sloved the problem using this:

```
setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Thread.sleep(500);//500ms was enough to finish stopFM before the second click
                if(isFmOn()){
                   //stopFM
                }else{
                  //do other things
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Ugg, sleeping in the UI thread is not a very nice thing to do! I don't this answers the OP's question either.

Comment: After single and double clicking of the button will perform separate operation,maybe the problem is in the onClick() function ,  Sometimes when you release audio resource,you have to wait until the the releasing operation done.                                                                          Maybe the better way to solve the problem is simply to set one globle variable count and increment in click even.