# Record user taps

Tags: java, android

I have a simple XML layout of four buttons. Within those four buttons, I wish to allow users to either single, double, or long tap each button as many times as they'd like. I'd also like to record which button they tapped and what type of tap it was (single, double, long). I have read around and saw maybe GestureListener is the way to go but I'm not sure. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I want to do this for all four buttons too. Just a little lost here. I have listeners set up on the buttons but they're on click listeners and I can't seem to find anything that would let me record the taps. Thanks.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353457/single-click-and-double-click-of-a-button-in-android) for clicks and double clicks and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402740/android-long-click-on-a-button-perform-actions) for long clicks (both are other stackoverflow questions)

Comment: @Soana I need to record them in the order they were tapped. Should i just set listeners for each type of tap and have them stored in a string array by type and order?

Comment: @Soana So if i just want to go with single and long taps, how would i record them as tapped? As in, type and order? So if button 2was long tapped and them button 4 single how could i record those as an array or something?