# How to set on double click listener on an ImageView in android?

Tags: android

I am making an Instagram clone app. I want to add the double click functionality. How can I set On Double Click Listener on an ImageView?

Comment: setOnTouchListener and use GestureDetector

Comment: check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58547495/12709358

Answer (score 0):

I was in your shoes before and came across this brilliant [Source code in Gtihub](https://gist.github.com/srix55/ec64d2f6a371c80bbbc4), it solves the problem by overriding `OnClickListeners`

It basically fulfills all your needs

- Double click listener On ImageView ✅
- Double click listener On Any other Views! ✅

I would highly recommend having a little more study on `OnClickListeners` as well. ([read more here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener))