# Double Click Problem in android with java

Tags: java, android, cardview

I had created a Java Class for double click but I am not able to double Click on the Item because when i click for only one time the item doesn't wait for double click !

Double Click Class Code

```
package com.programiner.studyvillaadmin.Classes.Listener;

import android.view.View;

public abstract class DoubleClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final long DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA = 300;//milliseconds

    long lastClickTime = 0;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        long clickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (clickTime - lastClickTime < DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA){
            onDoubleClick(v);
            lastClickTime = 0;
        } else {
            onSingleClick(v);
        }
        lastClickTime = clickTime;
    }

    public abstract void onSingleClick(View v);
    public abstract void onDoubleClick(View v);
}
```

Comment: Please refer this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353457/single-click-and-double-click-of-a-button-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private long mLastClickTime = 0;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000) //*1000 is time to perform second click*
            return; *// return when second click happen in second*
        mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        GameSound.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sound__(GameSound.buttonClick);

        if (v == findViewById(R.id.tvUsername)) {
            StartActivity(UserProfile.class);
        }
    }
```

**example**

`public long mLastClickTime = 0;` //declare and define public

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  //click lister of itemview of RV Adapter
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000) //*1000 is time to perform second click*
                                    return; // return when second click happen in second*
                                mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

                                //do stuff here...
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: as a beginner! can u plz provide me the whole code of your answer and also show how to implement this class in RV adapter

Comment: Okay,please check my edited answer.

Comment: Please refer this link if you don't understand.https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-introduction-to-gestures--mobile-2239#:~:text=6-,%40Override,%7D,-As%20with%20the