# How to handle double click on event onclicklistener in android studio?

Tags: java, android, button

Please help How to handle the double click  on event  `OnClicklistener` on the button, Cardview or others,

Comment: Checkout this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849115/implement-double-click-for-button-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below:-

**Java Version:-**

```
 private var doubleClickLastTime = 0L
    view.setOnClickListener {
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - doubleClickLastTime < 300){
                doubleClickLastTime = 0
                doAction()
            }else{
                doubleClickLastTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            }
        }
```

**Kotlin Version:-**

```
val doubleClickLastTime = 0L
view.setOnClickListener
run({ if (System.currentTimeMillis() - doubleClickLastTime < 300)
     {
       doubleClickLastTime = 0
       doAction()
     }
     else
     {
       doubleClickLastTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
     } })
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , its works :)