# I made an app in which if you click a button an audio will play and if you click twice it will stop but the stop function is working only once

Tags: java, android, audio

Hi I am new to coding and I am making an app in which if you click a button an audio will play and if you double click the button the audio will stop. But the stop function is only working once. How can I solve it. Here's the Code.

```
public class MainActivity extends 
AppCompatActivity {
private Button rrjk_btn, 
gdsph_btn, aspamm, stop_btn;
    int counter = 0;
    @Override
    protected void 
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.radhasoami_rakshak_jeev_ke);
    rrjk_btn = findViewById(R.id.rrjk_btn);
    rrjk_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (counter == 2)
            {
                mediaPlayer1.pause();
            }
            mediaPlayer1.start();
            counter++;
        }
    });
    //
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.guru_dhara_sheesh_par_haath);
    gdsph_btn = findViewById(R.id.gdsph_btn);
    gdsph_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer2.start();
        }
    });
    //
    aspamm = findViewById(R.id.gdsph_btn);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer3 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.ae_satguru_pita_aur_malik_mere);
    aspamm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer3.start();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: After pausing the audio you have to reset the counter to Zero. try this!

Comment: How can I do this?? I don't know because this is my first app!!

Comment: inside If block below mediaPlayer1.start(); so counter  = 0;

Answer (score 1):

Your counter int is always increasing so it will be equal to 2 once.
Check this code:

```
if (counter == 2){
   mediaPlayer1.pause();
   counter = 0;
} 
mediaPlayer1.start();
counter++;
```

Anyway, this code doesn't make any sense if you want to know if the user is double clicking the button. Check this:

[Implement double click for button in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849115/implement-double-click-for-button-in-android)