# Handaling single and double taps android kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to display some toast when my button is clicked once and other toast when my button is clicked twice. Is there any built in library or do I need to implement custom logic?

Comment: [GestureDetector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector) does support double tap. Though using this on a button just for double tap is kind of overkill and not necessarily simpler because it require overiding touch event. [Implementing your own logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849115/implement-double-click-for-button-in-android) woudn't be hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can Gesture Detector for detecting double taps.

```
final GestureDetector mDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

        return true;
    }
});
```

For more details you can check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by @TaranmeetSingh is absolutely right but there is a better solution. You can use [this](https://github.com/pedromassango/doubleClick) library to do it.

## How to implement

[image]

1. Add this library -> `implementation 'com.github.pedromassango:doubleClick:CURRENT-VERSION'`(Version is given above).
2. Instead of using an `onClickListenerObject` for onClickListener, you can use `DoubleClickListener` Check the example below

   ```
   Button btn = new Button(this);
   btn.setOnClickListener( new DoubleClick(new DoubleClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSingleClick(View view) {

            // Single tap here.
        }

        @Override
        public void onDoubleClick(View view) {

            // Double tap here.
        }
    });
   ```