# Viewflipper on double clicking the firstview third view appearing

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am newbie to android. I  have a doubt regarding the view flipper functionality. I have three views in my view flipper, when I double click on the first view third view appearing and also when I double click on the second view  instead of third view first view is appearing. how to stop this so that with double click also  it will go to the next view only, any Idea?

here is the code

```
public class gif extends Activity {
    ViewFlipper flipper;
  //    RelativeLayout r1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.second_view);



    private Animation inFromTopAnimation() {

    Animation inFromTop = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
    );
    inFromTop.setDuration(1000);
    inFromTop.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return inFromTop;
    }
    private Animation outToBottomAnimation() {
    Animation outtoBottom = new TranslateAnimation(
      Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
      Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f
    );
    outtoBottom.setDuration(1000);
    outtoBottom.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return outtoBottom;
    }

    private Animation outToTopAnimation() {
    Animation inFromTop = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
    );
    inFromTop.setDuration(1000);
    inFromTop.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return inFromTop;
    }
    private Animation outFromBottomAnimation() {
    Animation outFromBottom = new TranslateAnimation(
      Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
      Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f
    );
    outFromBottom.setDuration(1000);
    outFromBottom.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return outFromBottom;
    }



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
     ImageView imgview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);

     Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.flipback);

     imgview1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
             flipper.setInAnimation(inFromTopAnimation());
             flipper.setOutAnimation(outToBottomAnimation());
             flipper.showNext();      
         }
     });

     button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
             flipper.setInAnimation(outToTopAnimation());
             flipper.setOutAnimation(outFromBottomAnimation());
             flipper.showPrevious();

         }

     });


    }

     @Override
     public  void  onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
     ImageView imgview1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);                                        
     imgview1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
     imgview1.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.topimageview);

     AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =
     (AnimationDrawable) imgview1.getBackground();

     if (frameAnimation.isRunning()) {
        frameAnimation.stop();
     }

     else {
        frameAnimation.stop();
        frameAnimation.start();
     }

     ImageView imgview2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview2);                                        
     imgview2.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
     imgview2.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.rectbackground);

     AnimationDrawable frameAnimation1 =
     (AnimationDrawable) imgview2.getBackground();

     if (frameAnimation1.isRunning()) {
        frameAnimation1.stop();
     }

     else {
        frameAnimation1.stop();
        frameAnimation1.start();
     } 
     ImageView imgview3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview3);                                        
     imgview3.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
     imgview3.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.background1);

     AnimationDrawable frameAnimation2 =
     (AnimationDrawable) imgview3.getBackground();

     if (frameAnimation2.isRunning()) {
        frameAnimation2.stop();
     }

     else {
        frameAnimation2.stop();
        frameAnimation2.start();
     }
     ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview01);                                        
     imgView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
     imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.background);

     AnimationDrawable frameAnimation3 =
     (AnimationDrawable) imgView.getBackground();

     if (frameAnimation3.isRunning()) {
        frameAnimation3.stop();
     }

     else {
        frameAnimation3.stop();
        frameAnimation3.start();
     }
     ImageView imgview02 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview02);                                        
     imgview02.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
     imgview02.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.background3);

     AnimationDrawable frameAnimation5 =
     (AnimationDrawable) imgview02.getBackground();

     if (frameAnimation5.isRunning()) {
        frameAnimation5.stop();
     }

     else {
        frameAnimation5.stop();
        frameAnimation5.start();
     }

     ImageView imgview03 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview03);                                        
     imgview03.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
     imgview03.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.background2);

     AnimationDrawable frameAnimation4 =
     (AnimationDrawable) imgview03.getBackground();

     if (frameAnimation4.isRunning()) {
        frameAnimation4.stop();
     }

     else {
        frameAnimation4.stop();
        frameAnimation4.start();
     }

     ImageView imgview04 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview4);                                        
     imgview04.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
     imgview04.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.background4);

     AnimationDrawable frameAnimation6 =
     (AnimationDrawable) imgview04.getBackground();

     if (frameAnimation6.isRunning()) {
        frameAnimation6.stop();
     }

     else {
        frameAnimation6.stop();
        frameAnimation6.start();
     }
    ;
    final ImageView hearttap =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hearttap);
  // final View second = null ;

    Button ekgbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ekgbutton);

    final ImageView i2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview02);
     final ImageView i3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview03);
     final ImageView i4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview04);
     final ImageView i5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview05);
     final ImageView i6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview06);
     final ImageView i7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview07);


    hearttap.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private Animation inFromRightAnimation() {

            Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f

            );
            inFromRight.setDuration(500);
            inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            return inFromRight;
            }
            private Animation outToLeftAnimation() {
            Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
             Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f,
             Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
            );
            outtoLeft.setDuration(500);
            outtoLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            return outtoLeft;
            }


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //  r1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            i2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i7.setVisibility(View.GONE); 



             flipper.setInAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());
             flipper.setOutAnimation(outToLeftAnimation());
             flipper.showNext();

           //  flipper.getChildAt(2)
             flipper.setDisplayedChild(2);


           // WebView  webview1= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.ekgwebview1);
        //   webview1.loadUrl("C://Users/Android/Desktop/bg only.gif");
         // flipper.clearDisappearingChildren();

        // flipper.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(2);
             flipper.setEnabled(true);

             if (hearttap.onTouchEvent(event))


                 return true;
             else
                 return false;         

        }
    });

 ekgbutton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
     private Animation inFromLeftAnimation() {
            Animation inFromLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
            );
            inFromLeft.setDuration(500);
            inFromLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            return inFromLeft;
            }
            private Animation outToRightAnimation() {
            Animation outtoRight = new TranslateAnimation(
             Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f,
             Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
            );
            outtoRight.setDuration(500);
            outtoRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
            return outtoRight;
            }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i6.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            i7.setVisibility(View.GONE);    

            flipper.setInAnimation(inFromLeftAnimation());
             flipper.setOutAnimation(outToRightAnimation());
             flipper.showPrevious(); 
             flipper.setEnabled(true);

             //  flipper.getChildAt(0);
            flipper.setDisplayedChild(0);

            return true;

        }

    });

    }
    }
```

Comment: Can  you post your code?

Comment: @Deepak Hi, see the code which i posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in setting display child
On button click of `ekgbutton` You have set `flipper.setDisplayedChild(0);` which means first view will open. make it as `flipper.setDisplayedChild(2);`

```
flipper.setDisplayedChild(0) = display first view
flipper.setDisplayedChild(1) = display second view
flipper.setDisplayedChild(2) = display third view
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,but this nt the exact solution coz, with single click everything is working fine and the methods r also working fine, the only problem is with the double click remember :)

Comment: Hi James, Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217670/question-how-to-implement-android-double-tap

Comment: @James Long Press is a recommeded interaction in the UI Guidelines, double touch is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hasmap where you store cutton object as key and click counter as value. on each click increment the counter if the modulus division of the counter gives you zero then set disoplay the view. In this way you can handle double click event.

Thanks
Sunil

Answer (score 0):

Jamesdroid i had also occur the same problem the solution for the problem is that 
1.OnClick function **check which button_tab is pressed** that is in your case u have 3 views let it be v1,v2 and v3 now let also u include 3 buttons like tabs on button click you will display respective tab.
2. **Inside button click again check which is the current view is active or shown** then as per the current view got to the desired view by view.ShowNext().

following is the code for your referral where i had three views(view_beverages, view_dimsum, view_appetizers) and theree buttons(**tabs**) for this views.

ViewFlipper mVf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.MyViewFlipper);//My ViewFilpper showing 3 tabs(1.Beverages, 2.DimSum, 3.Appetizers)
public void onClick(View v) {
        // Beverages tab click
        if (v == btn_beverages) {

```
        btn_beverages.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.beverages_on);
        btn_dimsum.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dimsum_off);
        btn_appetizers.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.appetizers_off);

        View myCurrentView = mVf.getCurrentView();//Collecting the current displayed view.
        if (myCurrentView == view_beverages) {

        }
        if (myCurrentView == view_dimsum) {
            mVf.showNext();
            mVf.showNext();

        }
        if (myCurrentView == view_appetizer) {
            mVf.showNext();             
        }


    }
    // Dimsum tab click
    if (v == btn_dimsum) {

        btn_beverages.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.beverages_off);
        btn_dimsum.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dimsum_on);
        btn_appetizers.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.appetizers_off);

        View myCurrentView = mVf.getCurrentView();
        if (myCurrentView == view_beverages) {
            mVf.showNext();
        }
        if (myCurrentView == view_dimsum) {

        }
        if (myCurrentView == view_appetizer) {
            mVf.showNext();
            mVf.showNext();

        }

    }
    // Appetizer tab click
    if (v == btn_appetizers) {

        btn_beverages.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.beverages_off);
        btn_dimsum.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dimsum_off);
        btn_appetizers.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.appetizers_on);

        View myCurrentView = mVf.getCurrentView();
        if (myCurrentView == view_beverages) {
            mVf.showNext();
            mVf.showNext();
        }
        if (myCurrentView == view_dimsum) {
            mVf.showNext();
        }
        if (myCurrentView == view_appetizer) {

        }

    }
```