# Working on a project for visually disabled, NEED HELP with android coding!

Tags: android

i'm making an app on android smart phones for the visually impaired and i have inquiries. Now, my app's main menu is already created, and i've used text-to-speech program to read out the menu for the visually impaired. QN: what do i have to do to make it so that when visually impaird personnal press the buttons on the menu once, text to speech is activated, telling them what they are pressing, and to double tap to enter/activate the activity linked to the button? Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

Check out these resources that may help:

- [Designing for Accessibility](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/accessibility.html)
- [Google I/O 2011: Leveraging Android Accessibility APIs To Create An Accessible Experience](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPXqsPeCneA)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use GestureDetector for a double tap / double click solution.

See answers here for some solutions: [Android: How to detect double-tap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217670/question-how-to-implement-android-double-tap)