# How do I modify TouchImageView with double tap to zoom in and out?

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

I am modifying the TouchImageView (https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/issues) to have zoom in and out for when you double tap. I have started as per this post - [How does TouchImageView works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491519/how-does-touchimageview-works) and have added the gesture detection.

Now I have to implement the zooming in and zooming out which I am not sure how to do. Here is the code I have so far with the zoomIn and zoomOut methods unimplemented. Anyone know how to do this? In addition I noticed that the pinch zoom doesn't really zoom to the location where you pinch, so I was hoping that this could be made to behave more like the gallery3D pinch zoom. Thanks.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

private static final String TAG = TouchImageView.class.getSimpleName();

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 3f;
float[] m;

float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace;

float width, height;
static final int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
float right, bottom, origWidth, origHeight, bmWidth, bmHeight;

ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

Context context;

public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public void init(Context context) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new DoubleTapGestureListener());

    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                return true;
            }

            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                start.set(last);
                mode = DRAG;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                    float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                    float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                    float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);
                    if (scaleWidth < width) {
                        deltaX = 0;
                        if (y + deltaY > 0)
                            deltaY = -y;
                        else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                            deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                    } else if (scaleHeight < height) {
                        deltaY = 0;
                        if (x + deltaX > 0)
                            deltaX = -x;
                        else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                            deltaX = -(x + right);
                    } else {
                        if (x + deltaX > 0)
                            deltaX = -x;
                        else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                            deltaX = -(x + right);

                        if (y + deltaY > 0)
                            deltaY = -y;
                        else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                            deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                    }
                    matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                    last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                    performClick();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                break;
            }
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            invalidate();
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
    bmHeight = bm.getHeight();
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        LogUtil.i(TAG, detector.getScaleFactor() + " " + detector.getFocusX() + " " + detector.getFocusY());

        float mScaleFactor = (float) Math.min(Math.max(.95f, detector.getScaleFactor()), 1.05);
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }
        right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        if (origWidth * saveScale <= width || origHeight * saveScale <= height) {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                    if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width) {
                        if (y < -bottom)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                        else if (y > 0)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                    } else {
                        if (x < -right)
                            matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                        else if (x > 0)
                            matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                if (x < -right)
                    matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                else if (x > 0)
                    matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                if (y < -bottom)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                else if (y > 0)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    // Fit to screen.
    float scale;
    float scaleX = (float) width / (float) bmWidth;
    float scaleY = (float) height / (float) bmHeight;
    scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    saveScale = 1f;

    // Center the image
    redundantYSpace = (float) height - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
    redundantXSpace = (float) width - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
    redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
    redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

    matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

    origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
    origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
    right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
    bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
}

class DoubleTapGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    // event when double tap occurs
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "Tapped at: (" + x + "," + y + ")");
        if (isZoomed()) {
            zoomOut();
        } else {
            zoomIn();
        }
        return true;
    }

}

public boolean isZoomed() {
    return saveScale > minScale; // this seems to work
}

public void zoomIn() {
    LogUtil.i(TAG, "Zooming in");
    // TODO: no idea how to do this

}

public void zoomOut() {
    LogUtil.i(TAG, "Zooming out");
    // TODO: no idea how to do this
}

}
```

Comment: check [this fork](https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery) of **TouchImageView** with tap-to-zoom implementation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My answer might be not exactly specific to your problem but it covers ImageView Zooom in/out, double tap, Bounding image in Imageview when its zoomed , In short is exactly like the default Gallery app of Android

http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/

As the blog says:

> As long as Android doesn’t have a built-in ImageView widget with zoom and scroll capabilities I tries to create one by myself starting from the google repository.
>
> The result is pretty nice so I’m posting here the source code, if
>   anyone is interested, or simply doesn’t want to waste the time
>   creating a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Doubles the current zoom to zoom in, then returns to original zoom level:

```
float oldScale = 1.0f;
public void zoomIn() {
    LogUtil.i(TAG, "Zooming in");
    oldScale = saveScale;
    saveScale *= 2;
    matrix.setScale(saveScale, saveScale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    invalidate();
}

public void zoomOut() {
    LogUtil.i(TAG, "Zooming out");
    saveScale = oldScale;
    matrix.setScale(saveScale, saveScale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    invalidate();
}
```

You might want to translate the matrix to centre on the point the user double clicked.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me on my SGS2.. It zooms into a point and then doesnt zoom out.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't read all your code. Set a boolean when zooming in/out and use it in the onDoubleTap function instead of isZoomed

Answer (score 1):

@sherlock,

If you want to zoom out when double tap again, you can write a method as below:

```
private void handleScaleWhenDoubleTap(float scaleFactor) {
    //set original scale
    float origScale = curScale;
    //update current scale
    curScale *= scaleFactor;
    //fix current scale if it greater than max scale, recalculate scale factor
    if (curScale > maxScale) {
        curScale = maxScale;
        scaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
    }
    //fix current scale if it less than min scale, recalculate scale factor
    else if (curScale < minScale) {
        curScale = minScale;
        scaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
    }
    //calculate right point, bottom point
    right = (curScale - 1) * width - 2 * (redundantXSpace * curScale);
    bottom = (curScale - 1) * height - 2 * (redundantYSpace * curScale);
    //scale
    matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
    //translate
    matrix.getValues(m);
    float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

    if (y + bottom < 0) {
        if (x >= 0) {
            matrix.postTranslate(-x + redundantXSpace, -(y + bottom + redundantYSpace));
        } else if (x + right < 0) {
            matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right + redundantXSpace), -(y + bottom + redundantYSpace));
        } else {
            matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
        }
    } else if (y >= 0) {
        if (x >= 0) {
            matrix.postTranslate(-x + redundantXSpace, -y + redundantYSpace - navBarHeight);
        } else if (x + right < 0) {
            matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right + redundantXSpace), -y + redundantYSpace - navBarHeight);
        } else {
            matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
        }
    } else {
        if (x >= 0) {
            matrix.postTranslate(-x, redundantYSpace - navBarHeight);
        } else if (x + right < 0) {
            matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right + redundantXSpace), redundantYSpace - navBarHeight);
        } else {
            matrix.postTranslate(0, -navBarHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: In case a phone has Soft Navigation Bar (as Nexus 5), you have to recalculate the distance to translate. In my example, navBarHeight is the variable that be set by the function:

```
 public int getNavBarHeight(Context ctx) {
        int id = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier("config_showNavigationBar", "bool", "android");
        boolean hasNavBar = id > 0 && ctx.getResources().getBoolean(id);
        if (hasNavBar) {
            int resourceId = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
            if (resourceId > 0) {
                return ctx.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Double tapping and other gestures can be detected as follows: 
[Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

I hope this helps...
Emmanuel

Answer (score 0):

With the class **TouchImageView** above, if you want to apply **Double Tap**, you can do some steps:

1. Declare variable:

   ```
   GestureDetector mDoubleTap;
   ```
2. Init in constructor:

   ```
   mDoubleTap = new GestureDetector(new DoubleTapGestureListener());
   ```
3. Register in **onTouch()**:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       mDoubleTap.onTouchEvent(event);
       ...
   }
   ```
4. Write the method **handleScale()** - coppied from **onScale()** method - as below:

   ```
   private void handleScale(float mScaleFactor) {
       float origScale = saveScale;
       saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
       if (saveScale > maxScale) {
           saveScale = maxScale;
           mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
       } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
           saveScale = minScale;
           mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
       }
       right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
       bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
       if (origWidth * saveScale <= width || origHeight * saveScale <= height) {
           matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
           if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
               matrix.getValues(m);
               float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
               float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
               if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                   if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width) {
                       if (y < -bottom)
                           matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                       else if (y > 0)
                           matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                   } else {
                       if (x < -right)
                           matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                       else if (x > 0)
                           matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                   }
               }
           }
       } else {
           matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleDetector.getFocusX(), mScaleDetector.getFocusY());
           matrix.getValues(m);
           float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
           float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
           if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
               if (x < -right)
                   matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
               else if (x > 0)
                   matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
               if (y < -bottom)
                   matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
               else if (y > 0)
                   matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Put it in **zoomIn()** method as:

   ```
   public void zoomIn() {
       handleScale(2.0f);// 2.0f is the scale ratio
   }
   ```
6. In the override method **onScale()**, you can modify as:

   ```
    @Override
       public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
           float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
           handleScale(mScaleFactor);
           return true;
       }
   ```

to follow DRY principle.

***Note:*** double tap has only effect with small touched area.

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: it is working, but when i zoomout the center of the image is shifted in direction of the touch.e.g.  if you doubletapped on right of center so when you zoomout image is shifted to right side. I added   public void zoomOut() {
    handleScale(0.5f); isZoomed = false;} , any idea?

Comment: I have an answer for you, please check below. So sorry because it's too long to post here