# Zoom An Image ( Android Studio )

Tags: android, image, pinchzoom

Ok So I Have An Image Which Can Zoomed In And Out , But After Zooming It In ( By Pinching ) The Image Automatically Goes Back The Its Original Dimensions , What I Want Is That The Image Should Stay Zoomed In After I Zoom In And Take My Hand Off The Screen

For Example :- When You Zoom In An Image In Gallery The Image Stays Zoomed In Unless You Zoom Out

`Zoomy.Builder builder=new Zoomy.Builder(getActivity)).target(big).animateZooming(false).enableImmersiveMode(false); builder.register();`

Do I Have To Use Some Other Library Or Some Other Method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this library. This is the perfect library according to your requirement. You can also apply zoom in/out for video.

https://github.com/natario1/ZoomLayout

Comment: https://natario1.github.io/ZoomLayout/docs/zoom-image <- This Actually Helped Me , But Thanks Only Because Of You I Could Reach This Site !

Answer (score 2):

You can try [PhotoView](https://github.com/Baseflow/PhotoView) library as suggested in the 1st answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821489/double-tap-to-zoom-and-pinch-to-zoom-on-imageview-in-android/54474155) question.