# Loading Images from SD card to ViewPager Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-sdcard

I need to Load Images from a folder in SD Card into a ViewPager. This is what i have managed so far.

```
public Drawable getImageFromSdCard(String imageName) {
    Drawable d = null;
    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                + "/YourSubDirectory/";
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path + "/" + imageName
                + ".png");
        d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return d;

}
```

How can i set this as a ViewPager ?

Comment: Refer this tutorial http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/

Comment: Hey @Mridul S Kumar....i have same Queries to set last captured images into ViewPager......my Question link is.............http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066564/view-pager-can-not-display-last-captured-images

Comment: Please tell me if you know....i can not fetch last captued Images in View pager...Please once refer my question..because its seem's there is No Error their...):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need make adapter that extends PagerAdapter then set adapter to view pager

Try below code:

```
ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(new TouchImageAdapter());
```

**TouchImageAdapter class:**

```
class TouchImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            ImageView img = new ImageView(container.getContext());
            img.setImageDrawable(getImageFromSdCard(filename));
            container.addView(img, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            return img;
        }

        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }


    }
```

Here is your method used in adapter class

```
public Drawable getImageFromSdCard(String imageName) {
    Drawable d = null;
    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                + "/YourSubDirectory/";
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path + "/" + imageName
                + ".png");
        d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return d;

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Any idea how to add pinch zoom to the imageview ?

Comment: You have make custom class for zooming functionality to imagview . this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491519/how-does-touchimageview-works helps

Comment: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.example.touch.ExtendedViewPager app crashes

Comment: Hey Rajesh Bro....i have same Queries to set last captured images into ViewPager......my Question link is.............http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066564/view-pager-can-not-display-last-captured-images

Comment: Rajesh Bro. plz ke bhai jo tane Khabar hoi to...kem ke 2 days thaya solve karu chu...and bhul pan dekhati nathi.....);