# How to hide TabWidget of tabhost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I use tabhost in my app.
I use below code to add intent:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
Intent intent;
Resources res = getResources();

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Files").setIndicator("NAS Files", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic)).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

In AActivity, I want to hide the tabs(TabWidget) while the button was clicked.
And click two times to show tabs.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three states for view visibility in Android.

1. **visible** Visible on screen; the default value.
2. **invisible** Not displayed, but taken into account during layout (space is left for it).
3. **gone**  Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added.

Below are how you do so programatically.

```
tabhost.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
tabhost.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
tabhost.setVisibility( View.GONE );
```

So, you can set an `OnClickListener` on `tabHost` that modifies the visibility of the view.

```
private OnClickListener tabClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
    }
};

// Somewhere else in your code...
tabhost.setOnClickListener( tabClickListener );
```

To catch double taps, you can keep a counter of taps on the onClick and expire them after a time threshold.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217670/question-how-to-implement-android-double-tap) for more info on the double tap

Read the visibility api doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)

Comment: After add it, where click it will invisible?

Comment: I try click any position, it does not invisible.

Comment: but AActivity is different with TabActivity