# WebView Disable DoubleTap

Tags: android, webview, zooming, tap, disabled-control

I am developing an android application and successfully disabled zoom-in, zoom-out by swiping. But I have failed to disable double tap zooming.
Is there an obvious function to use?
Thanks.

Here is my code,

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
webview.loadUrl(url1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's a "feature" in WebView in pre-KitKat versions of Android, that double tap can be explicitly disabled only by turning off `UseWideViewPort` setting.

There are workarounds that based on "stealing" double tap events from WebView described in [WebView getting rid of double tap zoom.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301775/webview-getting-rid-of-double-tap-zoom) and [How to disable doubletap zoom in android webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951935/how-to-disable-doubletap-zoom-in-android-webview)

Answer (score 4):

add this

```
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
```

Comment: That does the trick but I need that setting to be true because of render issues. Any other opinion?