# Enable double tap to zoom in and out for html file

Tags: android, html, android-webview

Using Android Studio, I have created a WebView to show a local html file. Unfortunately, the double tap zoom doesn't seem to work inside the html file. However, I can still pinch to zoom in and out. Any idea how to enable it?

Comment: it should work by default. Probably you use some touch/click listeners that could prevent it?

Comment: Maybe it can help you -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301775/webview-getting-rid-of-double-tap-zoom?rq=1

Comment: @Vladyslav, i thought so, but it didn't unfortunately.  I guess the best bet is to follow the link that Milad gave.