# Double tap event in android

Tags: android

I need to toast something on double tap the screen. I tried the following code. But it's not working. No toast is coming on double tapping. What is wrong with these code?

```
package a.b.c;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class SampleActivity extends Activity implements OnDoubleTapListener,OnGestureListener
{
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        if(e.getAction()==1)
        {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onDoubleTap", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        if(e.getAction()==1)
        {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onDoubleTapEvent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        if(e.getAction()==1)
        {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onSingleTapConfirmed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I also implemented the OnGestureListener methodes. But have no effect. Please help.

Comment: why are you checking the condition of ACTION_DOWN  ?

Comment: When you post code, please post parts relevant to the question..Why put header file import in the post?

Comment: @neeraj, Actually if(e.getAction()==1) is also not working.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra, its not a big deal..

Comment: i have answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16232779/1000864)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where do you set the doubletap listener?  Try adding this to your oncreate and see if it fixes the issue

```
GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(this, this);
```

Comment: Whats TapDetector? Its not showing any built in class/method named TapDetector.

Comment: ok. now i need to know where should i invoke the detector object?