# How to implement double tap for gridview item

Tags: android, gridview, double-click

I want to implement gesture inside the Gridview item.

When i am doing double tap. have to show some animation
Is that possible is Grid view, if possible Please guide me to do this

Please share some snippets
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detecting a double tap gesture inside of a GridView item is described in this awesome post:
[Android: How to detect double-tap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217670/android-how-to-detect-double-tap)

Answer (score -1):

Extend *GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener* and override it's *onDoubleTap()* method

```
class DoubleTapGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Double Tap Detected ...");
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: hey please tell me how to implement this inside the gridview item

Comment: i do not know how to implement this in Grid view, plz guide me

Comment: Is that possible to implement double tap inside the grid view item?

Comment: @vinay Maneti, please tell the whole story instead of just providing a small portion of the code.