# How to handle click-event in RecyclerView.ItemDecoration?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a RecyclerView (with LinearLayoutManager) and a custom RecyclerView.ItemDecoration for it.

Let's say, I want to have buttons in the decoration view (for some reason..).

I inflate the layout with button, it draws properly. But I can't make the button clickable. If I press on it, nothing happening(it stays the same, no pressing effect) and onClick event is not firing.

The structure of ItemDecoration layout is

```
<LinearLayout>
  <TextView/>
  <Button/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I'm trying to set listener in ViewHolder of the decoration

```
class ItemDecorationHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView header;
    public Button button;

    public HeaderHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        header = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.header);
        button = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //.. Show toast, etc.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And i'm drawing the decoration in onDrawOver method. (actually, I'm modifying this codebase: https://github.com/edubarr/header-decor )

Any ideas? Is it doable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

While the real header is scroll off the screen, the visible one is drawing on canvas directly ,not like a normal interactive widget.

You have these options

1. Override RecyclerView.onInterceptTouchEvent(), though with some invasiveness so I prefer the next one.
2. Make use of RecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(), remember the motion event argument has been translated into RecyclerView's coordinate system.
3. Use a real header view, but that will go a little far I think.

> If you take option 1/2, Button.setPressed(true) and redraw the header will have a visual press effect.

Comment: In this case, it will take the click on the whole header. Please suggest something if I want to click on a particular position on the header.

Comment: How can i trigger an event if the click happens in a specific "button" in the header?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what [Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5307644/neil) said, 
the answer here might help.
 [Passing MotionEvents from RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener to GestureDetectorCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524003/passing-motionevents-from-recyclerview-onitemtouchlistener-to-gesturedetectorcom)

And then you just need to calculate the height of the header and see if the click falls onto that header view and handle the event yourself.

```
private class RecyclerViewOnGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        float touchY = e.getY();



        ALLog.i(this, "Recyclerview single tap confirmed y: " + touchY);
        //mGroupHeaderHeight is the height of the header which is used to determine whether the click is inside of the view, hopefully it's a fixed size it would make things easier here 
        if(touchY < mGroupHeaderHeight) {
            int itemAdapterPosition = mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().getPosition(mRecyclerView.findChildViewUnder(0, mGroupHeaderHeight));

            //Do stuff here no you have the position of the item that's been clicked
            return true;
        }
        return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        float touchY = e.getY();

        if(touchY < mGroupHeaderHeight) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onDown(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        float touchY = e.getY();

        if(touchY < mGroupHeaderHeight) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Neil is pointing out, things are getting more complicated than that. However by definition you can't.

So, why not including good libraries that do that and more?
I propose my hard work for clickable sticky header in my [FlexibleAdapter](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter) project, which uses a real view (not decorators) to handle click events on headers when sticky.

There's also a working demo and a [Wiki page](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter/wiki/5.x-%7C-Headers-and-Sections) on that part (and not only).