# How to handle the click on the sticky header decor in a RecyclerView?

Tags: header, android-recyclerview, decorator, sticky

I have a `RecyclerView` with a `StickyHeaderDecor` (with `Button`, `ImageView`, and `TextView` inside).

How do I handle the clicks on these components within the `StickyHeader`?

The [library used is `UltimateRecyclerView`](https://github.com/cymcsg/UltimateRecyclerView).

This is the code where I setup my `recyclerView`:

```
    StickyRecyclerHeadersDecoration headersDecoration =
            new StickyRecyclerHeadersDecoration(adapter);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(headersDecoration);
    StickyRecyclerHeadersTouchListener headersTouchListener =
            new StickyRecyclerHeadersTouchListener(recyclerView, headersDecoration);
    headersTouchListener.setOnHeaderClickListener(new StickyRecyclerHeadersTouchListener.OnHeaderClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onHeaderClick(View headerView, int position, long headerId) {
            Log.d(TAG, "clicked view " + v.getId() + " position:" + position);

            // my code here to handle click (*)
        }
    });
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(headersTouchListener);
```

(*) I don't have the possibility to handle click on `headerView`.

Comment: Please add code for what you've already attempted and be explicit about what isn't functioning as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not possible to easy handle click of part of item decor. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33051916/1016367) is an explanation why.

For Sticky Headers is better use:

- [FlexibleAdapter](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter)
- [SuperSlim](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM)