# OnClickListener for CardView is not working android?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have list of contacts and i have show this list on RecyclerView using CardView.

List is showing perfectly But now I want to make clickable Card View. So that When I click on particular contact i will show details of particular contact.

List is perfectly shown but when i click on particular contact click event is not working .

I have also used clickable true on CardView and OnClickListener event on ContactAdapter class .

What I did :

I have three layout activity_main, contact_list, contact_detail.

In activity_main i used recycler_view.
In contact_list i used card_view and bind it with recycler view.

I have three java class :
Contact - where i defined variable with getter and setter
ContactAdapter - where i get contacts and bind it with card view.
MainActivity - where i get all contacts and show it on recycler view.

activity_main layout code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

contact_list_layout code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:clickable="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Remo"
            android:id="@+id/person_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/person_name"
            android:text="example@gmail.com"
            android:id="@+id/person_email"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Java Class Code:

MainActivity Code :

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
String[] name,email;
ArrayList<Contact> list = new ArrayList<Contact>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.person_name);
    email = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.person_email);

    int count = 0;
    for (String Name : name)
    {
        Contact contact = new Contact(Name,email[count]);
        count++;
        list.add(contact);
    }
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter=new ContactAdapter(list,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

ContactAdapter code :

```
 ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
Context ctx;

public ContactAdapter(ArrayList<Contact> contacts, Context ctx) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_list_layout, parent, false);
    ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder = new ContactViewHolder(view, ctx, contacts);
    return contactViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Contact CON = contacts.get(position);
    holder.person_name.setText(CON.getName());
    holder.person_email.setText(CON.getEmail());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contacts.size();
}

public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView person_name, person_email;
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    Context ctx;

    public ContactViewHolder(View view, Context ctx, ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
        super(view);
        this.contacts = contacts;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        person_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        person_email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_email);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        Contact contact = this.contacts.get(position);
        Intent intent =new Intent(this.ctx,ContactDetail.class);
        this.ctx.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524003/passing-motionevents-from-recyclerview-onitemtouchlistener-to-gesturedetectorcom

Comment: you are not setting listener to your card view ?

Comment: @Manish answered, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, you are missed setting listener for your cardview. to trigger `onClick(View v)` method you have to set listener for the corresponding view.
example:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Contact CON = contacts.get(position);
    holder.person_name.setText(CON.getName());
    holder.person_email.setText(CON.getEmail());
    holder.card_view.setOnClickListener(this)
}
```

**UPDATED ViewHolder**

```
 public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView person_name, person_email;
        CardView card_view;
        ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        Context ctx;

        public ContactViewHolder(View view, Context ctx, ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
            super(view);
            this.contacts = contacts;
            this.ctx = ctx;
            card_view = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            person_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            person_email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_email);
        }
```

**EDIT**

Since your parent layout is CardView you can directly set listener without initiating

*Example*

```
public ContactViewHolder(View view, Context ctx, ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
    super(view);
    view.setOnClickListener(this);
    this.contacts = contacts;
    this.ctx = ctx;
    person_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
    person_email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_email);
}
```

Comment: In this holder.card_view.setOnClickListener(this) what is card_view ?

Comment: card_view you have to initialize in your ViewHolder class

Comment: where onclick will use ?

Comment: i didn't understand that query

Comment: where I will use this public void onClick(View v) { } method. ?

Comment: that is based on where you are setting the listener, if you are setting the listener in ViewHolder class you have use it there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103799/discussion-between-manish-tiwari-and-driodev).

Answer (score 8):

I fixed the same issue when I remove `android:clickable="true"` on item view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/item_dashboard_size"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/item_dashboard_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="@dimen/item_dashboard_padding">
    .....
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure you use the foreground and cardBackgroundColor of your card view

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/blue">
```

this must seem weird but works, cause without that the cardview is not triggering the OnClickEvent.

I have test and only with the  app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/blue" works!!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of implementing OnClickListener() in **ContactViewHolder** class (your private static class inside adapter), implement it inside **onBindViewHolder()** method.

Check this code.

```
@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_list_layout, parent, false);
    ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder = new ContactViewHolder(view);
    return contactViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Contact CON = contacts.get(position);
    holder.person_name.setText(CON.getName());
    holder.person_email.setText(CON.getEmail());
    holder.card_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         // your click code here
         }
     });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contacts.size();
}

public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView person_name, person_email;
    CardView card_view;

    public ContactViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        person_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        person_email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.person_email);
        card_view=(CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
    }

}
```

Comment: In this "holder.card_view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{"  card_view is  showing error because it is undefined in onBindViewHolder method. Can i initialize global.

Comment: card_view is initialized inside your static class ContactViewHolder, just like you initialize two TextView person_name, and person_email. See it inside the constructor of ContactViewHolder class.