# LibGdx double tap

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to detect double taps in libgdx using the tap method of the GestureDetector. GestureListener class. I searched the Web for the last two days but I couldn't find an example of how  to do it. I know that the method has a "count"  variable but I don't know how to use it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not specifically geared toward LibGDX, but it does answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217670/android-how-to-detect-double-tap

Comment: Thanks lokisinclair but I wanted a libgdx specific answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example of usage of GestureDetector with multiple tapping detection in one of libGDX's tests: [GestureDetectorTest.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/GestureDetectorTest.java).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. It works well now. I changed the code a bit because I am currently not working worth cameras and I separated the Controller class from the main class to make it cleaner. This was my first question on stackoverflow and I am positively surprised by the fast answers. I'll definitely recommend this site to others.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that the accepted answer doesn't provide enough details, so here is a small code snippet with implementation:

```
public class DoubleTapDetector extends GestureDetector.GestureAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
        if (count == 2) {
            System.out.println("Double tap!");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```