# What is the best way to handle double click on bottom navigation item to refresh fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I have in my app feature which requires double tap on bottom navigation item to reload fragment data and I've searched a lot but didn't find a good way to handle this action so please help me with my issue

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen an Android design that requires a double-tap. But ok, you just need to track the first tap, and if there is a second tap within 325 ms or so then trigger the double click effect.

Comment: i've already handled it in that way but i think that is not good practice so I'm asking if there is library which includes that feature

Comment: Any library would be doing the same thing, it's just code and this is what you need done

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a long tap but if you really want to use double tap maybe this thread can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6290044/3528912