# How to avoid single-click when entering double-click event?

Tags: java, android, onclick

Here's my basic code for discriminate single vs double click on Android/Java:

```
int i = 0;

buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        i++;
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                i = 0;
                onSingleClick();
            }
        };
        if (i == 1) {
            //Single click
            handler.postDelayed(r, 250);
        } else if (i == 2) {
            //Double click
            onDoubleClick();
        }
    }
});
```

The fact is: on single-click, it correctly call "only" `onSingleClick()`. On double-click, it call both `onDoubleClick()` and `onSingleClick()`.

What should I do? Reset `handler` in some way on `i == 2`?

Comment: Check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48844866/17856705) for a gesture listener approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cancel the `Runnable` when a double click is detected. This prevents the execution of `onSingleClick()` after `onDoubleClick()` has been identified.

```java
int i = 0;
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (i == 1) {
            onSingleClick();
        }
        i = 0;
    }
};

buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        i++;
        if (i == 1) {
            handler.postDelayed(r, 250);
        } else if (i == 2) {
            // Cancel scheduled single click handling
            handler.removeCallbacks(r);
            onDoubleClick();
            i = 0;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Seems working. Can I do r = new Runnable() within onClick instead of decleare it outside once?

Comment: Well you could try to refactor that code but you probably would end up with more code, and perhaps less readable because you'd need a logic to prevent creation of the `Runnable` on each click + logic to prevent use of `r` if it is null etc. not sure it's worth the fuss.

Comment: I mean declare Runnable r outsude, but doing "new" inside onClick()